# AJAX email form will not submit

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms, validation

I have an email sign-up form on my site that I recently added validation to.

Now, the form will not send or provide an error message. When I check the inspector I see the following error:

> TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById(update[0]).innerHTML = update[1]')

---

This is my `contact.php` file

```
 <?php
$to = "hello@interzonestudio.com";
$subject_prefix = ""; 

if(!isset($_GET['action']))

$subject = "Newsletter Sign Up"; //The senders subject
$message = trim($_GET['email']); //The senders subject
$email = trim($_GET['email']); //The senders email address

if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {

mail($to,$subject,$message,"From: ".$email."");

echo 'contactarea|<div id="thanks">Thank you. We promise you won’t regret it.</div>';

else {
  echo("$email is not a valid email address");
}
?>
```

This is my form in HTML

```
<div id="contactarea">
    <span style="font-family: 'Old Standard TT', serif;">Newsletter</span>
    <form id="contactform" name="contactform" >
        <input class ="email" type="text" name="email" id="inputbox" value="E-Mail"
onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="send" onclick="sendemail(); return false; " class="signup" >
        </form>
    </div>
```

and this is my javascript

```
<script language="javascript">
    function createRequestObject() {
        var ro;
        var browser = navigator.appName;
        if (browser == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
            ro = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } else {
            ro = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        return ro;
    }
    var http = createRequestObject();

    function sendemail() {
        var email = document.contactform.email.value;
        document.contactform.send.disabled = true;
        http.open('get', 'contact.php?email=' + email + '&action=send');
        http.onreadystatechange = handleResponse;
        http.send(null);

        setTimeout(function() {
            jQuery(document).find("#thanks").fadeOut();
        }, 3000);

    }

    function handleResponse() {
        if (http.readyState == 4) {
            var response = http.responseText;
            var update = new Array();
            if (response.indexOf('|' != -1)) {
                update = response.split('|');
                document.getElementById(update[0]).innerHTML = update[1];
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(update[0]);` to make sure your http response is being split and giving the correct ID for the element?

Comment: Thank you. I'm not sure what you mean by that. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Are you getting this error when you enter the wrong email? If so you need to add the `|` to your error message.  Your php reply is being split from `|` and the first array is being used to hold the Div ID, your php error reply (email) doesn't have a div id so it will cause problems when you split it. I think you need t replace `echo("$email is not a valid email address");` with `echo("DivID|$email is not a valid email address");` **Missing bar in the echo!**

Comment: You also have multiple errors in your PHP, `{` please read your php again. You will also need to change your ajax call type to `POST` not `GET`. you will also need to change this on the php file to `_POST[]` I want to post as a answer but if I do It would mean covering every error and this has too many.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:
document.contactform.send.disabled=false;

add another div in html page with id = "msg"

replace

document.getElementById(update[0]).innerHTML = update[1];

with

you can add conditions here
depending on what you want to display upload[0] or upload[1]
document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = update[0]+update[1];

and in contact.php

there is '}' missing before else.

Comment: Thank you! This validates, but if the user puts in a wrong email it won't send if they then put in a correct one

Comment: You still need to send this email address to connect.php. Because you are using PHP code for email validation.

Comment: Yes. do you know how I could do that?

Comment: If you want to validate form in html page you have to use javascript and validate the input characters entered.(regex) or you can use angulars.js(this would be the best choice).

Comment: If you want to validate form in html page you have to use javascript and validate the input characters entered(regex) and then you can enable or disable form submission if input is incorrect or you can use angulars.js(this would be the better choice).   At the moment you are not using form attributes ( onfocus, onblur). And this line document.contactform.send.disabled=true;  is not needed. Unless in your website is some code which requires this line.

Comment: @user4621032 believe it or not the only problem with the client-side is the call method should be post, not get & the form data isn't being sent. the document.getElementById() is working as it should, the PHP isn't set up as it should be to work with the rest.

Comment: NewToJS. If so, how you can get an element for which there is no 'id' in html page.

Comment: @user4621032 and what element would this be? You are aware that document.`contactform` will target all the elements withing the form allowing you to access them via name.  So document.contactform.send will target the form element with the name of send and in this form send is the submit button. document.contactform.send.disabled=true; will disable that submit button. So what element are you talking about?

Comment: NewToJS I meant response div  -  document.getElementById(update[0]).

Answer (score 0):

Multiple errors, client and server-side.

> Changes to javascript. Your form data wasn't being sent in the php call.

I have made changes to your call type get/post and used new FormData(). If you want to add more to your call `formdata.append("ParamName", Value/Variable);` and use `$something=$_POST['ParamName'];` to get the post in PHP.

```
var formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append("email", email);
formdata.append("action", "send");
http.open('POST', 'contact.php');
http.onreadystatechange = handleResponse;
http.send(formdata);
```

> Changes to PHP. You missed the opening/closing of the if statements.

The way you have your javascript setup, you split the php reply (|) if the email posted wasn't valid you would cause a JS error because you didn't have the divID and bar(|) in your echo.

```
$to = "hello@interzonestudio.com";
$subject_prefix = ""; 
if(isset($_POST['action'])){ // ***** Missing ({) 
$subject = "Newsletter Sign Up"; //The senders subject
$message = trim($_POST['email']); //The senders subject
$email = trim($_POST['email']); //The senders email address
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)===false) {
mail($to,$subject,$message,"From: ".$email."");
// **** Div ID Missing with Bar (contactarea|)
echo 'contactarea|<div id="thanks">Thank you. We promise you won\'t regret it.</div>';
// **** Else missing (})
}else {
  echo("contactarea|$email is not a valid email address");
}
}// **** Close if issset  (})
```

I hope I have covered all your problems in this answer.

If you don't understand anything please leave a comment below, i will update the answer to help you understand anything within this answer. I would rather you take this source code understand it, not just a copy paste. You won't learn from copy/paste.

> **`Tip:`** Clean your php string before putting them into mail().

I hope this helps. Happy coding!